"'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'" when using annotate with DateTimeField in Django ORM
I have configured db routers in my Django project and I need to use annotation on the query-set of a model with a model which has it's relation stored in a different database. The work around I am using for this is using a dictionary in the annotation. However, in the datetime field of the annotation, I am getting the following stack trace:
in localize(self, dt, is_dst)
    229     def localize(self, dt, is_dst=False):
    230         '''Convert naive time to local time'''
--> 231         if dt.tzinfo is not None:
    232             raise ValueError('Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)')
    233         return dt.replace(tzinfo=self)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'

This is how I have set up my code (took reference from this answer to a similar question):
from app1.models import Deal 
from app2.models import Contract 
from django.utils import timezone as django_timezone 
from django.db.models import Case, DateTimeField, Value, Case, When


deal_qs = Deal.objects.filter(<filters relevant to the flow>).values('id', 'final_amount', 'delivery_time', 'status__name')
deal_dict = {deal['id']: deal for deal in deal_qs} 


trade_object_ids = list(deal_dict.keys())
contracts = Contract.objects.filter(trade_object_id__in=trade_object_ids)


# This is where I define my annotation
delivery_date_annotation = Case(
    *[When(
        trade_object_id=key,
        then=Value(
            django_timezone.make_aware(
                django_timezone.datetime.strptime(
                    django_timezone.datetime.strftime(
                        deal_dict.get(key, {}).get('delivery_time'), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
                    ),
                    "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
                ),
                django_timezone.get_current_timezone()
            )
        )
        if deal_dict.get(key, {}).get('delivery_time')
        else None
    )
        for key in trade_object_ids
    ],
    default=Value(None),
    output_field=DateTimeField()
)

contracts = contracts.annotate(my_date_time_field=delivery_date_annotation)

please note that delivery_time in model Deal is already a DateTimeField.
however when calling contracts, I get the above mentioned error.
Can someone please guide me with the correct way of handling datetime attributes in cases like this one...
